# Get src attribute of thumbnail to modal in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want that after clicking on the thumbnail, the src will be downloaded and used in the modal. For now img is null, but i don't know why

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal_section");
const modal_img = document.querySelector(".b_p_modal");
const project_img = document.querySelectorAll(".project_img");
const close = document.querySelector(".modal_close");
const pic = document.getElementById("pic");

project_img.forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // modal_img.src = img.src;
    modal_img.setAttribute("src", img.getAttribute("src"));
    modal.classList.add("visible");
  });
});

close.addEventListener("click", function () {
  modal.classList.remove("visible");
});
```

```html
<div class="gallery_box">
      <div class="project_img"><img src="./images/projects/46.jpg"></div>
      <div class="project_img"><img src="./images/projects/45.jpg"></div>
      <div class="project_img"><img src="./images/projects/44.jpg"></div>
 </div>
  <section class="modal_section">
        <div class="photo_area_modal">
          <button class="modal_close">
            <span class="close_span"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="photo_big_modal">
            <img class="photoBig b_p_modal"/>
          </div>
        </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question. The problem in one word is your selection.

### Problem's cause

In your HTML code, you declared the images as:

```html
<div class="project_img"><img src="./images/projects/45.jpg"></div>
```

That means the div has the class of `.project_img` and image has no class.
Then on JS, your selection is:

```js
const project_img = document.querySelectorAll(".project_img");
```

So what is happening here is, you are selecting the `div` instead of the `img` since the dive has the class. Then when you are asking for `.src` property, div has no such property, so it's giving you null.

### Solution

So there are 2 solutions. First one is a unnecessary but you can the select the div's child nodes and the image from there. But the **Simplest solution is to add `class="project_img"` to the `img` tag** instead of the div.

So the code should be:

```html
<div><img class="project_img" src="./images/projects/45.jpg"></div>
```

I hope you got it.

Comment: It was actually a problem. Thank you very much :)